# Python merging two list into dictionaries, add values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Given the two following lists, one containing strings, one integers, how can I merge these two lists into a dictionary while ADDING the values for duplicate keys?

stringlist = ["EL1", "EL2", "EL1", "EL3", "El4"]

integerlist = [1, 2, 12, 4, 5]

So in the final dictionary I'd like EL1 to be 13, because it also contains 1 and 12.

```
resultdictionary = {}
for key in appfinal:
    for value in amountfinal:
        resultdictionary[key] = value
        amountfinal.remove(value)
        break
```

In this case, result dictionary removes any duplicate keys, but takes the last value that matches those keys. So, EL1 would be 12.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Test if the dictionary already contains the key. if it does, add to the value instead of replacing it.

Comment: Or use `defaultdict(int)`

Comment: Don't use nested loops. Use `zip()` to iterate over both lists in parallel.

Comment: FYI generally Python programmers, in contrast to Microsoft Win32 programmers, do not decorate their variable names with the variable's type. So, for example `resultdictionary` would typically be `result`.

Comment: And don't remove stuff from `amountfinal` as you go; [it causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/364696) if you change the size of a `list` while iterating it (not to mention being a lot slower; every `.remove` call is `O(n)`, and you do it `n` times, making the total work `O(n²)`, when bulk-clearing at the end with `amountfinal.clear()` would only require `O(n)` work total).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `defaultdict()` to create a dictionary that automatically creates keys as needed.

Use `zip()` to loop over the two lists together.

```
from collections import defaultdict

resultdictionary = defaultdict(int)
for key, val in zip(stringlist, integerlist):
    resultdictionary[key] += val
```

Comment: For the specific case of a `dict` with numeric values, `collections.Counter` *might* be better (it depends on the use case). From what the OP gave us, `defaultdict(int)` is more performant (it's entirely implemented in C on CPython, `Counter` is a Python-level subclass of `dict` with a few C accelerators tossed in), but `Counter` might be more self-documenting or be more useful for other reasons (counting iterables, not creating keys by simple access, etc.). This is still the right answer, just noting `collections.Counter` so folks who see it know there are two reasonable options here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger This isn't counting, it's summing. Can `collections.Counter` do that?

Comment: It has no special support for it, but it works the same as `defaultdict(int)` when you are doing `+=` like this (the `__missing__` implementation for `Counter` is literally just `return 0`, without inserting the key, so `resultdictionary[key] += val` will invoke `__missing__`, get `0`, leaving the `Counter` unchanged, add `val` to that `0`, *then* create the key-value mapping; `defaultdict(int)` would differ in that it would map `key` to `0` immediately, return the `0`, then add `val` and remap `key` to `0+val`). Net effect is identical either way.

Comment: In that case I don't see the point. The benefit of `collections.Counter()` is when you can just write `Counter(sequence)` and you don't have to write your own loop.

Comment: Agreed, I mention it only because many times you need to do both summing and counting, or you don't want merely doing `mydict[x]` to create a mapping from `x` to `0` (you want it to report `0` but not actually bloat the dictionary), or you want to figure out the most common elements after summation with `.most_common`, combine or subtract counts, etc. As I said, for the OP's case, `defaultdict(int)` covers all their described needs, but `Counter` is *often* useful in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `dict.get` with defaultvalue `0`. For example:

```py
stringlist = ["EL1", "EL2", "EL1", "EL3", "El4"]
integerlist = [1, 2, 12, 4, 5]

resultdictionary = {}
for s, i in zip(stringlist, integerlist):
    resultdictionary[s] = resultdictionary.get(s, 0) + i

print(resultdictionary)
```

Prints:

```py
{'EL1': 13, 'EL2': 2, 'EL3': 4, 'El4': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zany solution for funsies:

```
stringlist = ["EL1", "EL2", "EL1", "EL3", "El4"]

integerlist = [1, 2, 12, 4, 5]

result = {}
result.update((k, result.get(k, 0) + v) for k, v in zip(stringlist, integerlist))
print(result)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv/YohpwSDmLYePfbmH4gHwRiDIQ3JtqDit8fUVvSwzM4@dnbDna69b3JOFK03zibCDgfW7RWTKFLPsrjmI65lx6qynrTR8buiJGoJVaqV2BYedRrchJ6vpV8P4XwizflNYpkYTZPbCKwwClz6iGJHWI@HDfz3lcTfPSGqUADxOUXk/AY)

It's *almost* a one-liner, but still needs `result` to be defined as an empty `dict` *first*, so it can use a genexpr that lazily checks the value summed so far as it goes.

I don't actually recommend this. For one thing, I'm not sure the language spec strictly requires that `dict.update` evaluate the argument provided lazily; if it tried to optimize by eagerly converting it to a `dict` first, then merging, this would fail. For another, it's easily broken (a maintainer might blindly convert the genexpr to a dictcomp or listcomp and now it's eager and broken). And the genexpr, while it technically has no side-effects itself, is *relying* on the side-effects of it being consumed by `result.update`, which is a distinctly non-functional design at odds with the functional style of genexprs.

Answer (score -1):

The quickest way w/o imports would be like this:

```
stringlist = ["EL1", "EL2", "EL1", "EL3", "El4"]

integerlist = [1, 2, 12, 4, 5]

#Convert two Lists into Dictionary using zip()
mergeLists = dict(zip(stringlist, integerlist))
```

Comment: That discards the first pairing, because the `"EL1": 1` mapping is *replaced* by, not summed with, the `"EL1": 12` mapping seen later. The OP requires summation, which can't be done like this.